# SVG follows pointer animation stutter

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

The transition of the SVG that follows my pointer stutters when an SVG element is animated (translate, scale or rotate).

I update the `translate` properties of my SVG on `pointermove` event, and rely on CSS transition to make it smooth.

It works until I add a transform animation on one of the SVG element.

Something interesting is that when the window is not focused the transition remain smooth.

If I apply the transformation on the SVG container it remains smooth, but I need an animation on an SVG element.

Is there any secret property or technique to keep it smooth?

Thank you!

```js
const onPointerMove = (e) => {
  svg.style.translate = `${e.x}px ${e.y}px`
}

addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove)
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: translate 0.6s ease-out;
}

rect {
  animation: reshape 1s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes reshape {
  to {
    scale: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewport="0 0 100 100" id="svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I can see stutter in my Firefox, but I see it even without the animation on the <rect> (looks like the transition has some delay that gets reinitialized at each new event). However on my Chrome it's smooth, no matter what.

Comment: It seems that using 'mousemove' over 'pointermove' event fixes it in firefox, but stutters persist in my chrome :(

Comment: Have you tried debouncing the event? Like only calling it every 500ms or so?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by only updating on a `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
let requesting = false

const onPointerMove = async (e) => {
  if (requesting) return
  
  requesting = true
    
  await new Promise(r => requestAnimationFrame(r))
  
  svg.style.translate = `${e.x}px ${e.y}px`
  
  requesting = false
}

addEventListener('pointermove', onPointerMove)
```